# Clear a form after successful validation submit

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I have a from where i should fill the input fields to add new customer. Whn i submit the form without errors in the validation the customer will be added in the datatable but if i'll try to add another customer the form appears filled with the old values. I tried the script below but it doesn't work.

```
 <h:head>           
            <script>
                function handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, dialogName, formName) {
                    dialog = jQuery('#' + dialogName);
                    if (args.validationFailed) {
                        dialog.effect("shake", {times: 3}, 100);
                    } else {
                        customerDialogNew.hide();
                    }

                function clearForm(formName) {
                    jQuery('#' + formName).each(function() {
                        this.reset();
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </h:head> 
     <h:form id="form">          
     <p:panel id="panelform" header="Customers"  >
                     <p:dataTable value="#{customerMB.customers}" var="item" id="datas"  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25,30" 
                                  paginator="true" rows="10" filteredValue="#{customerMB.filteredCustomers}"
                                      selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{item.id}"
                                      selection="#{customerMB.selectedCustomer}">
                         <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:dataView,:form:customerUpdate , :form:updateButton,
         :form:viewButton" listener="#{customerMB.onRowSelect}"/> 
                         <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{item.name}" filterBy="#{item.name}" >
                             <p:outputLabel value="#{item.name}"/>
                         </p:column>
                      ...
                     </p:dataTable>
       </h:form>

<p:dialog draggable="true"   header="New Customer" widgetVar="customerDialogNew" resizable="false" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold"  style="position: absolute ;"  id="dialog2">            
                <h:form  id="newCustomerForm" > 
                <p:panelGrid id="newCustomer" columns="2" >   
                    <p:focus context="newCustomer" />  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <p:graphicImage value="/pictures/customerAdd.jpg"/> 
                    </f:facet>  
                    <p:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
                    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{customerMB.name}" title="Name" required="true" requiredMessage="The Name field is required."/>                
                    <p:outputLabel value="FamilyName:" for="familyName" />
                    <p:inputText id="familyName" value="#{customerMB.familyName}" title="FamilyName" required="true" requiredMessage="The FamilyName field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Country:" for="country" />
                    <p:inputText id="country" value="#{customerMB.address.country}" title="Country" required="true" requiredMessage="The Country field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Town:" for="town" />
                    <p:inputText id="town" value="#{customerMB.address.town}" title="Town" required="true" requiredMessage="The Town field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Street:" for="street" />
                    <p:inputText id="street" value="#{customerMB.address.street}" title="Street" required="true" requiredMessage="The Street field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Zip Code:" for="zipcode" />
                    <p:inputText id="zipcode" value="#{customerMB.address.zipCode}" type="number" title="zipcode" required="true" requiredMessage="The ZipCode field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Status:" for="maritalstatus" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="maritalstatus" value="#{customerMB.status}" required="true" requiredMessage="The Status field is required." >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Status"  itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{customerMB.allStatuses}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu> 
                    <p:outputLabel value="Gender:" for="sex" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="sex" value="#{customerMB.sex}" required="true" requiredMessage="The Gender field is required.">
                        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Select Gender" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{customerMB.allGenders}"  />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>                    
                    <p:outputLabel value="Email:" for="email" />
                    <p:inputText id="email" value="#{customerMB.email}" type="email" title="Email" required="true" validatorMessage="Insert a valid email" requiredMessage="The Email field is required.">
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Pseudo:" for="pseudo" />
                    <p:inputText id="pseudo" value="#{customerMB.login}" title="Pseudo" required="true" requiredMessage="The Pseudo field is required."/>
                    <p:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password : " />  
                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{customerMB.password}" feedback="true" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true" requiredMessage="The Password field is required."/>  
                    <p:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Confirm Password : " />  
                    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{customerMB.password}" feedback="true" label="Password 2" required="true" requiredMessage="The confirm password field is required."/>  
                    <p:outputLabel value="Right:" for="right" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="right" value="#{customerMB.right}" required="true" requiredMessage="The Right field is required.">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Right" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{customerMB.allRights}"  />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>  
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton   style="height: 100%;width: 25%" value="Cancel"  icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n" onclick="customerDialogNew.hide();" >                        
                </p:commandButton> 
                <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-priority-primary"  style="height: 100%;width: 25%" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"  actionListener="#{customerMB.addNewCustomer()}"  update=":form:panelform, newCustomer"  oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'customerDialogNew', 'newCustomerForm');">      
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: You could simply use `<input type="reset" />` for this purpose

Comment: when i add type="reset" to the inputText it doesn't work and i can't even write in the field

Comment: its a reset button, not a text box

Comment: What is the scope of your bean ?

Comment: @Adarsh SessionScoped

Comment: @Nouphal.M if i make the type of the button reset it will clear the form but don't call the add method in the bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your bean is Session scoped. The bean object created for the first customer is still present in the Session map. So everytime the page loads, the getters of that object is called and the fields in the page are populated with those values you set during the last form submit. You can either change the scope of your bean to RequestScope if your page doesn't contain any data that would be needed throughout the user Session. With Request scope, for every request a new instance is created. So everytime you submit the form(for every request), the current values will get persisted and the page loads with a new bean instance. Or, you can clear the properties in the bean corresponding to the fields on the page after persisting the data from the previous submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form .form_element').each(function(){ 
    this.reset();
});
```